# Is there similar Swift like "Any" type in Dart?

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I am new to dart and exploring some of its features. After searching everywhere I found "dynamic" is used for similar like any object. But I want to pass any class as a function parameter. Similar to the swift "Any".

I want to create a generic service call method which can return dynamic class model.

I am using `Future method`

Comment: Why not use `dynamic`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ## Object
>
> The base class for all Dart objects.
>
> Because `Object` is the root of the Dart class hierarchy, every other Dart class is a subclass of `Object`.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Object-class.html

Comment: Can it be used for a list (Array)?

Comment: Yes I have to declare something like List <Object>

Comment: I dont want that otherwise I have to create two different method one for list and one for object.

Comment: @Nick That sounds suspicious. What are you doing exactly?

Comment: I want to create a similar swift method like this, `func apiCall(anyBaseUrl: String = "", apiFunction: ApiName,
                 method m: HTTPMethod = .get, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil,
                 isJsonEncoding: Bool = false,
                 completion: @escaping (Bool, Any?, Error?) -> Void) {`

Comment: Here "Any" type is single struct or [struct]

Comment: @Nick Honestly, that's not a very good API design in Swift, either. `anyBaseUrl` should be a `URL`, not a `String`, the parameters dict shouldn't be optional, it should just default to an empty dict, the `Bool` parameter should probably replaced my polymorphism, and the parameter for the `completion` method should be a `Result<T>`, not a `(Bool, Any?, Error?)`. Most importantly, in the case you provided, I highly doubt that `Any` *really* means any. If I give you a `UIViewController`, how will your code handle it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196951/discussion-between-alexander-and-nick).